# Redmine plugin install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, redmine

I just installed redmine via apt-get on Linux Mint 14. Before I added the repository from https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/redmine. Everything works fine.

Environment:

- Redmine version 2.3.1.stable
- Ruby version    1.8.7 (x86_64-linux)
- Rails version   3.2.13

Next step would be for me to install a few plugins. I followed the instructions on 
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugins.

The plugin to install http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine-projects-accordion

1. I created a directory /plugins under /usr/share/redmine (this is
   where also the app-folder is).
2. Next step to do a  rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production.
   Now im getting a little Warning: WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.
3. Next step is to restart apache(using passenger-mod) to restart
   redmine. But there is no plugin on my administration.

As Im not a ruby/rails dev I can only guess where to search. Any ideas where to look for further information etc? Would be thankful for any advice.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Redmine is a ticket system as well as it is a issue tracker. Some companies are recently using redmine and it is developed by rails frame work. Now Redmine is upgraded its version to 2.x (recently 2.3 is the stable version). So , How can we use plugins in redmine 2.3 versions which we already implemented in redmine 1.x version.

Generally we can easily search the plugins from redmine plugins directory and do install , migration and restart the server i am sure some of you may get some issue at configuration level of the plugin from admin panel. So it depends up on the plugin version too. 
You can find the better approach to install the plugins in redmine 2.3 in step by step process is explained in detail from this blog

http://mywayonrails.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/plugins-for-redmine-2-3